# Difference between regular gcc and Mac OSX gcc?

Tags: macos, gcc

I am trying to port a piece of C++ code that is used in Windows to MacOS. The Windows C++ code used gcc as the compiler, and some gcc built-in functions that grabs machine related information like cpuid.h.

The problem is when I try to compile the code in Xcode. Most of the functions that grabs machine related information cannot be recognized by the compiler, and generate a lot of compiler errors for me.

Like the following statement:

```
#include <cpuid.h>
```

Gives me the following error msg:

```
Cpuid.h: No Such file or directory
```

Is there any difference between the GCC in Mac OSX and regular GCC?

Comment: The compilers themselves are very similar, but the included libraries may not be identical. Are you sure that your Mac OS X installation includes the `cpuid.h` header that you're using?

Comment: Good question! I am totally a newbie here. Could you direct me to a page or teach me how to get an installation with cpuid.h in?

Answer (score 2):

There are some differences, but they're relatively minor. It's much more likely that the functions you're using are Windows-specific, but you'd have to post some sample code.

Comment: I just update the question with sample codes in it. Thank you.